# How can I use async Method in Xamarin Forms when App starts?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to know How can I use async Method in Xamarin Forms when App starts?
I need to show front page based on the condition.

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (SaveCredential.IpAddress == string.Empty || SaveCredential.PortNo == string.Empty)
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Dhoni.IpDetail());
            }

            else if (SaveCredential.IpAddress != string.Empty && SaveCredential.PortNo != string.Empty)
            {
                if (await LoginPage.ConnectionCheck())

                {
                    if (SaveCredential.UserName != string.Empty && SaveCredential.Password != string.Empty)
                    {
                        if (await LoginPage.PasswordCheck(SaveCredential.UserName, SaveCredential.Password))
                        {
                            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Dhoni.Dashboard());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Dhoni.LoginPage());
                        }
                    }
                    else if (SaveCredential.UserName == string.Empty || SaveCredential.Password == string.Empty)
                    {
                        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Dhoni.LoginPage());
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Dhoni.IpDetail());
                }
            }
        }
```

I get error in these lines

> if (await LoginPage.ConnectionCheck())
>
> if (await
>   LoginPage.PasswordCheck(SaveCredential.UserName,SaveCredential.Password))

Error is

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider
>   marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return
>   type to 'Task'.

Anyone have solution for this??

Comment: check this https://www.xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-async-task-startup/

Answer (score 7):

```
    protected async override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        // call your async method here
    }
```

Comment: I need to set mainpage bage based on the async condition. If I placed my code in Onstart , cod is running but getting error or InitializeComponent(); 
Because, there is no Mainpage definition in public App(){}

Answer (score 1):

You can't use async/await in the ctor, read through async/await on msdn.

You have two options, you either override `OnStart` or `OnResume` (theres also `OnSleep`) and set them to async:

```
protected override async void OnStart() { //await ... }
```

or you set the `App.Current.MainPage` in the ctor of App.xaml.cs and then await your logic in the `override asnyc void OnAppearing()` of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** need to do that (but i advice not to):

```
YourMethodAsync.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```cs
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    //--- async code ---
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        //--- update UI ---
    });
});
```

when you call `Task.Run()` a new thread is created and you can call await in that thread and after the async method is done call `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` to update the UI because only the main thread can update UI.

Also you can use activity indicator to show the user that the data is loading.